# OCUnit deprecated warning

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I converted all the project to XCTest a while ago, but I always get this warning on XCode startup. If I try "Convert to XCTest" I get "no source changes necessary" and warning is removed. But next time I open Xcode+Project it all starts again.

I think there must be traces of OCUnit somewhere in project files, but I can't find them.
It's really annoying. Any help with removing this warning will be greatly appreciated.